# Preciso de um script(JQUERY) que acesse outra página e salve os dados.

Tags: php, jquery

Desculpem não ter mostrado nenhum código, pois não achei uma solução lógica.
Preciso de um script que acesse outra página e salve os dados sem eu estar naquela página entendem?
Exemplo:
Você está na index.php e possui $dado $dado2.

Agora a missão é: Enviar estes dados para a outra página, salvar os dados no submit de outra página. Tudo isso sem estar presente na outra página entendem?

Comment: Vc tentou usar o json do jquery?

Comment: Não conheço isso como é?

Comment: Vou formular uma resposta exemplo

Comment: Eu disse Json, mas na verdade é AJAX. O sono já está batendo...

Comment: Faça um tour para que você obtenha melhores resultados nas suas perguntas. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve aproveita e veja esse post também https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível "controlar" uma página sem está nela. Ou pelo menos, não de forma fácil.

A depender do que você realmente queira, o melhor seria utilizar o **[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** para fazer essa requisição na página *index.php*

Algo como:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.example.com/form.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        inputUm: "Your Name",
        inputDois: "Your Message"
    }
});
```

Comment: Isso não resolve o problema mocinho rsrs.

Comment: Pode ser um javascript..

Comment: Editei a resposta, adicione o POST, antes estava enviando como GET. Se puder exemplificar de outra forma, talvez fique mais fácil compreender. O que entendi foi que o usuário estará na página index.php e você quer dar possibilidade dele entrar em contato sem estar na página de contato. Mais ou menos isso.

Comment: Preciso de um script que acesse outra página e salve os dados

Comment: Preciso de um script que acesse outra página e salve os dados sem eu estar lá.

Comment: @AndressaLimão Quando você preenche um formulário e o submete, uma requisição HTTP será feita, no geral, POST. Para você simular tal atividade, você pode recriar manualmente esta requisição e enviá-la diretamente à URI que trata o formulário. De certa forma, é exatamente isso que o Valdeir colocou na resposta, embora mal explicado. Se este formulário está, ainda, em outro domínio, você terá que estudar sobre CORS.

Comment: na verdade eu ainda nao emtendi a necessidade disso. Para que vc faria isso? Acessar um formulario de um outro site que vc nao tem acesso direto? Mais fácil criar um iframe do site na pagina que esse formulario está.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o `AJAX` do `JQUERY`:

Antes de mais nada você precisa da biblioteca JQUERY linkada no seu script assim:

```
<script src='jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Imagine que você tem esse formulário na sua `index.php`:

```
    <form>

        <input id="dado1" type="text">
        <input id="dado2" type="text">
        <input id="enviar" type="submit">

    </form>
```

Quando clicar em enviar, o ajax enviará os valores dos inputs para a página `armazenaDados.php`

```
   <script>
    $('#enviar').on('click',function(){ 

        var dado1 = $('#dado1').val();
        var dado2 = $('#dado2').val();

        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'armazenaDados.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data: { dadoA: dado1, dadoB: dado2 },
            success: function(data) { 
               alert("alterado!"); 
            } 
        }); 

    });
</script>
```

No arquivo `armazenaDados.php` você recupera esses valores:

```
<?php

$dado1 = $_POST['dadoA'];
$dado2 = $_POST['dadoB'];

.... código que armazena os dados...
```

Comment: so lembrando que se o request nao for para o mesmo dominio voce pode ter problemas com [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS) dependendo de como estiver o `access-control-allow-origin` do outro servidor

Comment: "Muito Obrigada Andrei, mas meu objetivo é submeter dados não estando em uma página entende?";

Comment: @AndressaLimão esse dados vao para um banco de dados?

Comment: Porque talvez você esteja pensando em um caminho errado. Porque vc precisa fazer isso?

Comment: Oque vc quer é inserir dados em um formulario aonde vc nao tem acesso para que ele seja submetido automaticamente? É isso? Se for isso me responda... porque? Talvez eu consiga uma soluçao mais viavel.. Acho que nem é possivel fazer do jeito que vc quer, pois os formularios sao controlados pelo cliente e nao pelo servidor.